# Delphi - convert physical path (device File handle) to virtual path

Tags: delphi, path, virtual

How can I convert a path like

\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows

into its corresponding virtual path? (like c:\Windows in this case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I prefer the native way:

```
function GetHDDDevicesWithDOSPath:TStringlist;
var
  i: integer;
  root: string;
  device: string;
  buffer: string;
begin
  setlength(buffer, 1000);
  result:=TStringlist.create;
  for i := Ord('c') to Ord('z') do
  begin
    root := Char(i) + ':';
    if (QueryDosDevice(PChar(root), pchar(buffer), 1000) <> 0) then
    begin
      device := pchar(buffer);
      result.add(format('%s = %s\',[device, root ]));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**NB**: This code sample is taken from: http://www.delphipraxis.net/165249-auflistung-devices.html

This will return a map between logical drive and path. In my case:

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume2 = c:\
\Device\HarddiskVolume3 = d:\
\Device\IsoCdRom0 = e:\
\Device\CdRom0 = f:\
\Device\hgfs\;Z:0000000000084af9\vmware-host\Shared Folders = z:\
```

You have to replace "\device\harddisk" part in your path with coresponding drive letter.

Please, note drive letters are user dependent.
Some useful links:

- [Defining an MS-DOS Device Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [coverting physical drive to logical drive how to?](http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?t=2266)

Comment: For modern versions of Delphi, you could make the result more usable by returning a `TDictionary<string, string>` so that the caller doesn't have to do any more string parsing to find the desired entries.

Comment: This is extremely fast anyway. I adapted the code a bit, using it to find the path to a file being used by a process, iterating through the device paths until it finds the match to be used for conversion. It takes an average 40 microseconds (0.04 ms) in my test environment.

Answer (score 2):

One of approaches would be using WMI, for example http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magwmi.asp - it also has a demo that you can use to take code samples from.

You can find a number of WMI Explorers and explorer the configuartiona classes and construct queries. To name few free ones:

- Microsoft WMI CIM Studio is bad at making queries, but can be nice to view classes
- WMI Explorer from www.ks-soft.net turned to be the one i used the most

You would also need to google for WMI Query Language examples and read [specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa394606.aspx): while WMI language resembles SQL queries it has a bit different syntax and a set of hard to predict non-uniform restrictions.

---

Personally i used it in the different direction: i needed to make a list of volumes (drive letters), grouped by physical disk or network server.

I ended with (quick and quite ugly, but sufficient for one-time work at program initialization) unit like below. You can do stream-lining on it, and you'd definitely would have to reverse requests and functions.

```
unit WMI_Helper;

interface

function WMINetDiskName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
function WMIPhysDiskName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
function WMIGetVolumeName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;

implementation

uses magwmi, SysUtils, StrUtils, Windows, IOUtils;

function WMIGetProp(const query, param, resultProp: string): string;
begin
  if MagWmiGetOneQ(StringReplace(query, '%s', param, []), resultProp, Result) <= 0
  then
    Result := '';
  Result := Trim(Result);
end;

function WMINetDiskName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
const
  req = 'select ProviderName from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk where DeviceID = "%s"';
  prop = 'ProviderName';
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := WMIGetProp(req, disk, prop);

  If not TPath.IsUNCPath(Result) then
    exit('');

  i := PosEx('\', TPath.GetPathRoot(Result), 3);
  if i <= 0 then
    exit('');

  SetLength(Result, i - 1);
end;

function WMIPhysDiskName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
const
  resultProp = 'DeviceID';
  reqPart = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="%s"} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition';
  reqDisk = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="%s"} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskDrive';
begin
  Result := WMIGetProp(reqPart, disk, resultProp);
  if Result > '' then
    Result := WMIGetProp(reqDisk, Result, resultProp);
end;

function WMIGetVolumeName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
const
  prop = 'VolumeName';
  reqNet = 'select VolumeName from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk where DeviceID = "%s"';
  reqPhy = 'select VolumeName from Win32_LogicalDisk where DeviceID = "%s"';

begin
  Result := WMIGetProp(IfThen(GetDriveType(PChar(disk)) = DRIVE_REMOTE, reqNet,
    reqPhy), disk, prop);
end;

end.
```

---

I did not tried letter-less volumes (such as c:\ and c:\Windows would be one partition, and c:\Windows\Temp would reside on quite another disk), but if you need to account for such configuration, i believe you can make a proper query in WMI Explorer and add it to your program as well.

Comment: +1 for the solution, but (again) WMI is easy to use, powerful, BUT slow. And is not guaranteed to work correctly (broken repository, slow startup etc). Tip: when using WMI in a windows service, make sure your service depends on WMI service

Comment: WMI seems very slow indeed, ~230ms for a call to WMIPhysDiskName, whereas the other method in the 1st answer takes only 0,1ms to list all devices.

Comment: Look under the hood. In this code each call is self-contained: it creates TCP connection, then creates a tree of COM objects, then gets single property and destroys all that. You can google for sample of WMI in Delphi - there are more complex code, that re-uses those objects where appropriate. For my task it is enough, to once query all drive letters (of which actually 90% chance only C: would exists and be of HDD type). But you can re-use objects instead.