# Find volume information after attaching a virtual hard disk

Tags: windows, winapi, vhd

I used the Windows Disk Management snap-in to create, initialize, and format some virtual hard disks (VHD).  I can easily attach and access these VHDs manually but I am having trouble managing them through the API.

I cannot find an easy way to determine the drive letter for the virtual disk's volumes after it is attached.  I found the following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764697/create-a-virtual-partition) but its seems pretty convoluted.  Is there a better way?

Here's what I have so far... it's not much.

```
var
  StorageType: TVirtualStorageType;
  Path: UnicodeString;
  Handle: THandle;
begin
  StorageType.DeviceId := VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_DEVICE_VHD;
  StorageType.VendorId := VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT;

  Path := 'C:\tmp\small-usb.vhd';

  OpenVirtualDisk(@StorageType, PWideChar(Path), VIRTUAL_DISK_ACCESS_ALL,  OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE, nil, @Handle);
  AttachVirtualDisk(Handle, nil, ATTACH_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE, 0, nil, nil);
  // volume is visible in windows explorer at this point but   
  // I don't know the drive letter
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is the best way to do it, but you can use `GetVirtualDiskPhysicalPath` to get the path of the mounted VHD in the "`\\.\PhysicalDriveX`" format.  Using that path, you can query get the disk object for the volumes the disk contains (don't forget, a VHD can have multiple partitions and volumes, just like a physical hard disk), and then get a list of the assigned mount points (not necessarily drive letters - the VHD could be mounted at an NTFS mount point).

I'm not familiar with the language that you're using in the sample you've provided.  Is that Delphi?

Comment: Yes that's Delphi.  Do you know the name of the functions I would use to get the volumes from the physical path?

Comment: Not so familiar with Delphi but did come across this function **function GetHDDDevicesWithDOSPath**. Check this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696320/delphi-convert-physical-path-device-file-handle-to-virtual-path) and see if this helps